# check checkbox in onViewCreated() dynamically

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox, android-adapter

i need to check all checkbox in onViewCreated() when i lunch app but with this code

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        lv = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);

        ck=(CheckBox)getView().findViewById(R.id.chk_box);



        displayPlanetList();


        CheckBox chBox;
        for (int i = 0; i < lv.getCount(); i++) {
            view = lv.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
            chBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chk_box);

            chBox.setChecked(true);
        }

        plAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



    }
```

checkboxes are all unselected.

I don't know why.

I show you my code!

CUSTOM ADAPTER:

```
public abstract class PlanetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Planet> implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener, View.OnClickListener

{
    private List<Planet> planetList;
    private Context context ;
    ArrayList<Birra> objects;
    public boolean Checked;
    private Integer[] imageId;
    String ciao;
    static PlanetAdapter plAdapter;
    String selState ;
    boolean[] itemChecked;

    public PlanetAdapter(List<Planet> planetList, Context context,Integer[] imageId) {
        super(context, R.layout.single_listview_item,planetList);
        //itemChecked = new boolean[planetList.size()];

        this.planetList = planetList;
        this.context = context;
        this.imageId = imageId;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }



    public class PlanetHolder {
        public TextView planetName;
        public TextView distView;
        public TextView valuta;
        public CheckBox chkBox;
      //  public EditText edit;
        public TextView caratteristica;
        public TextView id;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public Spinner spinner;
        public NumberPicker np;


    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return planetList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Planet getItem(int position) {
        return planetList.get(position);
    }






    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        PlanetHolder holder = null;



        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_listview_item, parent, false);
            holder = new PlanetHolder();
            holder.planetName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.distView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.dist);
            holder.valuta = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.valuta);
            holder.chkBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.chk_box);
         //   holder.edit = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            holder.spinner = (Spinner) row.findViewById(R.id.simpleSpinner);
            holder.np=(NumberPicker)row.findViewById(R.id.np);
           // holder.edit2 = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
          //  holder.iterator = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.iterator);
           // Button iterator=(Button) row.findViewById(R.id.iterator);
           // iterator.setOnClickListener(this.PlanetHolder);
            holder.caratteristica=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.caratteristica);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
         //   holder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         //   holder.edit.setEnabled(false);
            holder.spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          //  holder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            // holder.id = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.id);


            row.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (PlanetHolder) row.getTag();


        }



        final Planet p = planetList.get(position);
        System.out.println("stampato P" + p);
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        holder.planetName.setText(p.getName());
        holder.distView.setText("" + p.getDistance());
        holder.valuta.setText("" + p.getValuta());
        holder.chkBox.setChecked(p.isSelected());
        holder.chkBox.setTag(p);
        holder.caratteristica.setText(p.getCaratteristica());

        // holder.edit.setEnabled(false);

        SharedPreferences states = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean isChecked = states.getBoolean("holder.chkBox" + holder.planetName.getText().toString(), false);
        System.out.println(isChecked);


        //holder.chkBox.setChecked(true);


        if (isChecked) {



            holder.spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.np.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);







        } else {
            holder.chkBox.setChecked(false);
          //  holder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          //  holder.edit.setEnabled(false);
            holder.spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.np.setVisibility(View.GONE);

         }


        holder.chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(PlanetAdapter.this);



        final PlanetHolder finalHolder = holder;
        Planet z=getItem(position);
        System.out.println(z);



       /* holder.chkBox.setChecked(true);
        holder.spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.np.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);*/


       // holder.chkBox.setChecked(true);



        holder.chkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                if (finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked()) {
                   // finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   // finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(true);
                    finalHolder.spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    finalHolder.np.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    finalHolder.np.setMaxValue(10);
                    finalHolder.np.setMinValue(0);
                    finalHolder.np.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
                   // finalHolder.np.getMinValue();
                   // System.out.println("valore picker alla selezione della checkbox"+finalHolder.np.getMinValue());

                    // finalHolder.edit2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                            getContext(),
                            R.array.country_arrays,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    //finalHolder.spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                    finalHolder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            finalHolder.spinner.setSelection(position);
                          //  selState = finalHolder.spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                         //   p.setQuantità(finalHolder.edit.getText().toString().trim());
                            p.setTipo(finalHolder.spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());

                          //  finalHolder.edit2.setText(selState);
                          //  System.out.println(selState);
                            System.out.println("p.getTipo()"+p.getTipo());

                           /* Toast.makeText(
                                    getContext(),
                                    "Clicked on Planet: " + selState + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/



                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                        }


                    });
                    finalHolder.np.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                            p.setQuantità2(newVal);
                            System.out.println(p.getQuantità2());
                            SharedPreferences states = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = states.edit();
                            editor.putInt("finalHolder.picker" + finalHolder.planetName.getText().toString(), finalHolder.np.getId());
                            editor.commit();
                        }
                    });



                    SharedPreferences states = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = states.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("holder.chkBox" + finalHolder.planetName.getText().toString(), true);
                    editor.commit();



                } else {
                    finalHolder.spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    finalHolder.np.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    finalHolder.np.setValue(0);


                }

            }
        });




        return row;
    }
```

FRGMENT:

```
public class MyListFragment extends Fragment  /*implements
        CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener, View.OnClickListener*/ {


    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<Planet> planetList;
    static PlanetAdapter plAdapter;
    private TextView txtName;
    private TextView txtEmail;
    private Button btnLogout;
    ListView listView;
    String user = "";
    private Spinner spinner;
    String selState;
    EditText cristo;
    private String zao;
    CheckBox ck;
    //private SQLiteHandler db;
    private SessionManager session;
    BirraAdapter biAdapter;
    PlanetAdapter.PlanetHolder holder;
    private static Context context = null;
    private static FragmentActivity mInstance;
    ArrayList<Integer> hm=new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<Integer,String> ar=new HashMap<>();


    Integer[] imageId = {
            R.mipmap.androtuto,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            R.mipmap.ok,
            /*R.drawable.image6,
            R.drawable.image7
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()" +
                    "                                .getAbsolutePath() + /ordinazioni/16:Maggio:2017-13:36:38 Pm.xml*/

    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        /*try {
            int a=0;
            String status="";
            boolean statuss = false;
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsolutePath() + "/ordinazioni/16:Maggio:2017-21:48:49 PM.xml");
            FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);

            Element element = doc.getDocumentElement();
            element.normalize();

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("checkboxes_pizza");

            for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = nList.item(i);
                if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element element2 = (Element) node;
                    //tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"\nName : " + getValue("name", element2)+"\n");
                    String id = getValue("id", element2);
                    a = Integer.parseInt(id);
                    status = getValue("status", element2);

                    statuss= Boolean.parseBoolean(status);

                    System.out.println("XML:" + a);

                    hm.add(a);




                    }

                }

            for(int i=0;i<hm.size();i++){
                int z=0;
                z=hm.get(i);
                System.out.println("XML STATUS:" + z);

                for(int j=0;j<plAdapter.getCount();j++){
                    Planet p=plAdapter.getItem(j);

                    System.out.println("XML STATUSS:" + p.getName());


                    if(p.getId()==z){

                        System.out.println("XML STATUSSS:" + p.getName());

                        p.setSelected(statuss);
                    }

                }




            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/



}

    private static String getValue(String tag, Element element) {
        NodeList nodeList = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getChildNodes();
        Node node = nodeList.item(0);
        return node.getNodeValue();
    }




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the custom_spinner_items for this fragment
        //super.onDestroy();

        SharedPreferences settings = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();


        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false);




        //ck=(CheckBox)rootView.findViewById(R.id.chk_box);



        //lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        //ListAdapter listAdapter = new MyListAdapter(getContext());
        //lv.setAdapter(listAdapter);



        context = getActivity();
        mInstance = getActivity();
        btnLogout = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);


        return rootView;
    }



    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        lv = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);

        ck=(CheckBox)getView().findViewById(R.id.chk_box);



        displayPlanetList();


        CheckBox chBox;
        for (int i = 0; i < lv.getCount(); i++) {
            view = lv.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
            chBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chk_box);

            chBox.setChecked(true);
        }

        plAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



    }



    private void displayPlanetList() {

        planetList = new ArrayList<Planet>();
        planetList.add(new Planet(1, "Margherita", "6", "€", "(pomodoro e mozzarella)"));
        planetList.add(new Planet(2,"Diavola", "7","€","(pomodoro,mozzarella e salsiccia piccante)"));
        planetList.add(new Planet(3,"Bufalina", "5","€","(pomodoro e mozzarella di bufala)"));
        planetList.add(new Planet(4, "Marinara", "5", "€", "(pomodoro)"));
        planetList.add(new Planet(5,"Viennese", "4", "€", "(pomodoro,mozzarella e wrustel)"));

        plAdapter = new PlanetAdapter(planetList, getContext(),imageId) {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                String pero="";

                int la=0;
                int pos = lv.getPositionForView(buttonView);

                System.out.println("POS:"+pos);


                if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                    Planet p = planetList.get(pos);

                    p.setSelected(isChecked);



            Toast.makeText(
                    getActivity(),
                    "Clicked on Pizza: " + la + ". State: is "
                            + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }

        };

        lv.setAdapter(plAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Answer (score 0):

```
   `chBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chk_box);`
```

You search only one checkBox-> R.id.chk_box. In the for.

Comment: sorry, so what is the solution?

Comment: I think you need to make a list ofor checkBox when you create them. Then make a for on this list, like, for each checkBox in listCheckBox. And then make them checked